Ansible playbook fails instead of running rescue block
I have the following Ansible playbook:
- hosts: <host>
  become: true
  vars:
    dest_dir: <dir>
  roles:
    - {role: '<role>', tags: '<tag>'}

The called <role> consists of a single task file:
- name: Copy and check file.
  block:
    - name: Copy
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        src: <source file>
        dest: "{{dest_dir}}"
        mode: 0666
        owner: root
        group: root
        backup: true
      register: copy_result
    - name: Print result
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: copy_result
    - name: Validate
      ansible.builtin.shell: <script> 1
      when: copy_result is changed
  rescue:
    - name: Revert
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        remote_src: true
        src: "{{copy_result.backup_file}}"
        dest: "{{dest_dir}}"
      when: copy_result.backup_file is defined

The called <script> is a dummy one, simply to exit with an exit code matching the supplied argument:
exit $1

(This code is based on the Ansible FAQ answer at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/faq.html#the-validate-option-is-not-enough-for-my-needs-what-do-i-do.)
If I run this when the destination file already exists but has different content to the source file, Ansible will correctly copy the source file to the destination, and I would expect the 'Validate' stanza to result in the 'rescue' block then being invoked, which should "roll back" the file copy.  However, the 'rescue' block is not invoked; instead, the playbook aborts from within the 'Validate' stanza with the message:
TASK [<task> : Validate] ******************************************************
fatal: [<host>]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "<script> 1", "delta": "0:00:00.010525", "end": "2024-09-17 10:49:23.559180", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2024-09-17 10:49:23.548655", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

It then enters the debugger.
I did wonder whether the 'when' parameter of the 'rescue' block was at fault here, but commenting it out resulted in the same behaviour.
Can anyone identify what I am doing wrong here?

First, note that the ansible.builtin.copy module has a validate option. Using that, you could rewrite your playbook like this:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    dest_dir: /tmp
  tasks:
  - name: Copy
    ignore_errors: true
    ansible.builtin.copy:
      src: testfile
      dest: "{{dest_dir}}/testfile"
      mode: 0666
      owner: root
      group: root
      backup: true
      validate: sh -c 'exit 1' -- %s
      # in practice, this would probably be a path to a script, like:
      #
      # validate: /path/to/validation-script %s
      #
      # The `%s` gets replaced by the path to a temporary file with the
      # content to validate.


You get effectively the same behavior with significantly less code.

With respect to your question, I cannot reproduce the error you show. You didn't provide one in your question, so I've crafted the following minimal, reproducible example:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    dest_dir: /tmp
  tasks:
  - block:
      - name: Copy
        ansible.builtin.copy:
          src: testfile
          dest: "{{dest_dir}}"
          mode: 0666
          owner: root
          group: root
          backup: true
        register: copy_result

      - name: Print result
        ansible.builtin.debug:
          var: copy_result

      - name: Validate
        ansible.builtin.shell: "exit 1"
        when: copy_result is changed
    rescue:
      - name: Revert
        ansible.builtin.copy:
          remote_src: true
          src: "{{copy_result.backup_file}}"
          dest: "{{dest_dir}}"
        when: copy_result.backup_file is defined

Running this produces (I'm using the unixy stdout callback to reduce output):
- localhost on hosts: localhost -
Copy...
  localhost done
Print result...
  localhost ok: {
    "changed": false,
    "copy_result": {
        "backup_file": "/tmp/testfile.893626.2024-09-17@07:11:55~",
        "changed": true,
        "checksum": "22596363b3de40b06f981fb85d82312e8c0ed511",
        "dest": "/tmp/testfile",
        "diff": [],
        "failed": false,
        "gid": 0,
        "group": "root",
        "md5sum": "6f5902ac237024bdd0c176cb93063dc4",
        "mode": "0666",
        "owner": "root",
        "secontext": "unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0",
        "size": 12,
        "src": "/home/lars/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1726571514.9080791-893587-119392786896945/.source",
        "state": "file",
        "uid": 0
    }
}
Validate...
  localhost failed | msg: non-zero return code
Revert...
  localhost ok

- Play recap -
  localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    rescued=1    ignored=0

We can clearly see that the "Revert" task is running. However, note that the "Revert" task does not do what you want. In the above example, our target file is /tmp/testfile, which means the backup file is named something like /tmp/testfile.893626.2024-09-17@07:11:55~. This makes the "Revert" task the equivalent of:
- name: Revert
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    remote_src: true
    src: "/tmp/testfile.893626.2024-09-17@07:11:55~"
    dest: "/tmp"
  when: copy_result.backup_file is defined

And that's a no-op; you're copying the backup file onto itself. If you wanted to replace the target file, you would need to provide an explicit filename in the dest parameter rather than a directory; that would make the playbook look like this:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    dest_dir: /tmp
  tasks:
  - block:
      - name: Copy
        ansible.builtin.copy:
          src: testfile
          dest: "{{dest_dir}}/testfile"
          mode: 0666
          owner: root
          group: root
          backup: true
        register: copy_result

      - name: Print result
        ansible.builtin.debug:
          var: copy_result

      - name: Validate
        ansible.builtin.shell: "exit 1"
        when: copy_result is changed
    rescue:
      - name: Revert
        ansible.builtin.copy:
          remote_src: true
          src: "{{copy_result.backup_file}}"
          dest: "{{dest_dir}}/testfile"
        when: copy_result.backup_file is defined

Running that successfully reverts the file when the "Validate" task fails.

thanks, you are absolutely correct about my rescue being a no-op. FYI the 'validate' option does not fit my needs: this code will eventually be used to copy sudoers files into place, and for that I need to validate the entire collection of sudoers files on the destination machine, not just the one copied sudoers file. Otherwise, you can break Sudo, even with a valid copied file.  I've also discovered I can avoid dropping into the debugger with an export ANSIBLE_ENABLE_TASK_DEBUGGER=False (leaving the configuration file setting unchanged, for the benefit of other users who want this).

It seems as if the validate option would still work just fine: it can run an arbitrary script, so whatever you would normally do in your "Validate" task, just put that into the script.
